What wording is most appropriate for an American company name meant to sound German?
I am designing a logo for a client whose family is from Austria back in the recesses of time. He wants to both honor that and glean some of the associations of German quality in design and manufacture as it applies to his bespoke, handmade loudspeakers.
His surname is Neiss (think Weiss) and we are going to utilize the "loudspeaker" cognate of "lautsprecher" as it is close enough for people to understand the company's offerings but purposefully very ethnic. If we were to be strict about it, I believe the authentic name for "Neiss Loudspeaker Company" would be "Neiss Lautsprecherunternehmen" which for obvious reasons is less than ideal...
Here's the question then. Are there any German company logos which utilize a variation of the word "Company" or the abbreviation "Co." that anyone knows of? I did read another post where a similar question about a business named "Adler & Co." was discussed, but this is not the same as the word "company" refers to the nature of the organization (meant to describe it is a maker of things) versus referring to the staffing makeup being comprised of people other than, but additional to, Adler. Make sense?
I think we'll likely opt for Neiss Lautsprecher Co. and call it a day, but I figure it is important enough to dig a bit before committing to that. I wonder though, would it be better perhaps to go with Neiss Lautsprecher Compagnie instead? I kinda doubt it because we aren't trying to fool people into thinking we are a German company, but rather just being reverential and/or referential. Thanks!
PS - Ever seen when the C is bigger than the O and they underline the second letter and make it small and float high up to the right of the company name? I don't think I will go that route, but it makes me wonder, does it look like "Co." or is that me assuming it would be abbreviated the same way by a German graphic designer as an American one, like me?

"I think we'll likely opt for Neiss Lautsprecher Co." If you want something with that "oldfashioned" flair (like some "shops" which style themselves as "shoppe") you can replace the "Co." with "Cie.", which is short for "Compagnie".

The very German word is Lautsprecherunternehmung

Are you marketing to the US or German speaking countries? I'm pretty sure that makes a difference because German speakers will notice if German is used incorrectly; Americans probably not so much. (The name "Häagen-Dazs" is meant to look and sound Danish, but the name doesn't mean anything in any European language and the company was founded in Brooklyn. Most Americans either don't know this or don't care.)

"Cº", with Unicode U+00BA is a misappropriation from Spanish, where it is the masculine ordinal indicator. I've never seen it in German for "Compagnie".

When something is "meant to sound German", wouldn't you rather ask Americans what they think sounds German? It is not clear that speakers of German are in a good position to answer such a question.


I believe the authentic name for "Neiss Loudspeaker Company" would be "Neiss Lautsprecherunternehmen"

Maybe this is just my subjective impression, but it would seem that in German, explicitly naming something "Company" or "Corporation" or similar is not all that usual in the first place.
That is, the full name of the business as registered with authorities would probably include something denoting the legal organisation structure - this is where the abbreviations mentioned in ccprog's answer are used. This name would be used in tax documents, it might appear in the footer of business letters and probably in the full "imprint" of the business website.
However, you are asking about a logo, or more generally, the way how the business presents itself to customers in marketing materials. In a wider sense, I imagine this would include the lettering on a storefront or on the roof of an office or factory building, for example. And typically, these would only say:
Neiss Lautsprecher

+1 In German, a typical official name for a company has the form   , e.g. Neiss Lautsprecher GmbH or Neiss Elektronik KG.  For the brand, you wouldn't mention the last part at all. It's also the most likely part to change in the future.

GmbH and KG are very different company types. Make 100% sure you pick the correct one.

Be careful if you want to market your products in German-speaking countries. There are a number of terms, including their abbreviations, that denote the legal structure of a company and are protected by German, Austrian, and Swiss Trade Law (Handelsgesetzbuch / Unternehmensgesetzbuch / Obligationenrecht).
The appreviation "& Co." is used in some contexts, as in "GmbH & Co. KG". The "Co." here stands for "Compagnie". It denotes one or more unnamed partners (here, in a limited partnership business), and its usage in the company name is obligatory, at least in Germany.
I am absolutely no expert on trade law and don't know whether the usage of "Co" on itself will pose a legal problem. For that, Law will be a better place to ask. But for German-speaking customers, it runs the risk to project a wrong expectation about the financial structure of the company. They will automatically read the "Co" as and Partners.
For the same legal reasons, you should avoid the terms "Gesellschaft" and "Unternehmen".

Some other terms are definitely not protected, and are quite often seen. None of them have common abbreviations:

Lautsprecherfabrik: Old fashioned, but with a feeling of respectability and workmanship. (This is the one I would go with.)
Lautsprecher-Manufaktur: Denotes small production numbers and that "everything is handmade". Used by "trendy" startups.
Lautsprecherwerkstatt: A workshop that might also be only doing repairs, so probably not for your case.

